Anime with two girls and two boys who have watches that can summon animal mechs from another world
It's an anime that's no older than 2012? I think.
It's from my childhood and I don't remember much, but the things I remember are:
Two girls, two boys. They have watches that can summon animal mechs from another world. The said mechas are a red T-Rex, a white tiger, a yellow bird, and a blue rhino. The mechs could combine to form a huge, powerful one.
The mechas were in 3D, but I don't think any of the other characters are.
Please help me find this anime. I swear it's making me lose sleep

This is Mix Master: Final Force (2010-2011).
It's a South Korean-Singaporean anime and a sequel series to Mix Master: King of Cards (2005-2006), featuring mostly 2D animation with some 3D elements.
From Amazon Prime Video:

After becoming the legendary Mix Master, Ditt now leads a boring, normal life as a student. But when the fantasy world faces another crisis, Ditt must join with other Mix Masters who are called upon to battle evil forces. The evil villain, Root, is determined to destroy both the Real World and the Fantasy World and create a new world of his own.


The story is set in a town called Gamebridge on Earth which is linked to Atreia, the homeworld of intelligent monsters known as hench.
The protagonists are two boys -- Ditt Lee and Ray -- and two girls -- Aring and Moreen -- who attend the same school in Gamebridge. Ditt was also one of the protagonists in Mix Master: King of Cards, whereas the other three are new to this series.
In the first episode of this series, the protagonists are recruited by four hench who want them to become the legendary Mix Masters and save both worlds from the antagonist of the show, Root. They're given wrist-worn devices called mix launchers that enable them to transform the four hench from their regular forms, which are small and cute, into their much larger battle hench forms.
Ditt's hench, Chi-Chi, transforms into a red robot T-Rex called Dino King. Ray's hench, Mir, transforms into a white robot big cat called Leo Khan. Aring's hench, Ang-Ang, transforms into a yellow robot hawk called Gold Hawk. And Moreen's hench, Ninom, transforms into a blue robot rhino called Ultra Horn. They can also combine with one another to form a variety of more powerful robots.




it is!!! thanks so much
